# Multiple_Matching_Token_Detected: Add-AzureAccount in Powershell

Tags: azure

When I try to run "Add-AzureAccount" command in the powershell, I encountered the error below:
I am using the latest Azure powershell version 0.87

> Add-AzureAccount : multiple_matching_tokens_detected: The cache
>   contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements. Call
>   AcquireToken again providing more requirements (e.g. UserId) At line:1
>   char:1
>
> - Add-AzureAccount
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell` and delete `WindowsAzureProfile.xml`. That helped me.

Comment: There is a TokenCache.dat file in that directory too.  I had to delete that one as well for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest version.  There was an issue around collisions in the token store that was fixed.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases/tag/v0.8.8-September2014